# Getting average score lower than the subject’s average score

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the data like this:

```
table students
studentid   studentname
1           ani
2           budi
3           caca
4           dedi
....        ... 


table subjects
subjectid   subjectname
1           MATH
2           ENG
3           SCIENCE
4           ART
....        ...         


table scores
studentid   subjectname   score
1           1              90
2           2              80
3           3              77
4           4              80
....        ...            ...
```

i want to get:

1. which subject has the 2nd highest score of all test results. Show the name of the subject and the score.

expected result :

```
  subjectname          score
         ENG             80
         ART             80
```

i have try this query:

```
SELECT st.studentname, su.subjectname, MAX(sc.score)
FROM scores sc
left join subjects su on su.subjectid = sc.subjectid
left join students st on st.studentid = sc.studentid

WHERE score<>(
SELECT MAX(score)
FROM scores);
```

but the output:

```
  subjectname    score
  ENG             80
```

how can i handle this ?

2. Print every student who had scored lower than the subject’s average score per student.

- Show the name of the student,
- name of the subject,
- average score per student of the subject,
- the student’s score.

my query was:

```
    SELECT st.studentname, su.subjectname, avg(score), sc.score
FROM scores sc
left join subjects su on su.subjectid = sc.subjectid
left join students st on st.studentid = sc.studentid
WHERE score <
    (SELECT  AVG(score) 
     FROM scores );
```

but the result wrong, the average show the avg of all subject not per subject.

how can u handle ?

Comment: you forgot groupby?

Comment: niceee, its work, thank you, how about the seocnd questions ? @lone_coder ?

Comment: you had a problem designing your database. should it be just calling "subjectid" rather than subjectname? (on table scores)

Comment: what's the point creating 'subjectid" anyway if you ain't gonna use it for reference to the other table?

Comment: as for your second question. you could've just use WHERE statement on your groupby table result. (e.g SELECT * FROM [your previous student average result] WHERE `studentscore` <  `your average column name`)

Comment: ah i see, i'm wrong for designing table of score, i have done edit. i'll try the query that u suggest @lone_coder

Comment: my query for second question was 


`SELECT st.name, su.name, avg(score), sc.score
FROM scores sc
left join subjects su on su.id = sc.subject_id
left join students st on st.id = sc.student_id
WHERE score <
    (SELECT  AVG(score) 
     FROM scores );`  but the average get from all subject didnt grup per subject

Answer (score 1):

Since there are ties in the scores one way to get the 2nd highest score is with this query:

```
select max(score)
from scores
where score < (select max(score) from scores)
```

Now join `subjects` and `scores` (`students` is not needed) and use the above query in the `WHERE` clause to get the subjects with that score:

```
select sb.subjectname, sc.score
from subjects sb inner join scores sc
on sc.subjectid = sb.subjectid
where sc.score = ( 
  select max(score)
  from scores
  where score < (select max(score) from scores)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fa079ae2530e8bd8742b35db43d1d219).
Results:

```
> subjectname | score
> :---------- | ----:
> ENG         |    80
> ART         |    80
```

For the 2nd question, this query:

```
select subjectid, avg(score) avg_score
from scores
group by subjectid
```

returns the average score of all subjects and you can join it to the 3 tables:

```
select st.studentname, sb.subjectname, t.avg_score
from students st 
inner join scores sc on sc.studentid = st.studentid
inner join subjects sb on sb.subjectid = sc.subjectid
inner join (
  select subjectid, avg(score) avg_score
  from scores
  group by subjectid
) t on t.subjectid = sb.subjectid and t.avg_score > sc.score
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT st.studentname, su.subjectname, sc.score

FROM scores sc

left join subjects su on su.subjectid = sc.subjectid

left join students st on st.studentid = sc.studentid

WHERE sc.score < AVG(sc.score)

GROUP BY  st.studentname,su.subjectname

Comment: its didnt works for me, the error was 'Unknown column 'sc.score' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT subjectname, avg_score
FROM (SELECT su.subjectname, AVG(sc.score) as avg_score,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(sc.score) DESC) as ranking
      FROM scores sc JOIN
           subjects su
           ON su.subjectid = sc.subjectid
      GROUP BY su.subjectname
     ) s
WHERE ranking = 2;
```

Comment: thank u, but i have an error like `Column 'subjects.subjectname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: i got the output from your answer, but you only show the all avg score, i want to print every student who had scored lower than the subject’s average score per student. it means, you should print student, subject,  avg_subject, and score